# Where does $\frac12$ come from in this integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following integration that was given as an example but I do not understand where $\color{red}{\frac12}$ comes from. Please explain.

$$\int (2x-1)^4 dx=\color{red}{\frac12}\int(2x+1)^4\times 2\;dx=\color{red}{\frac12}\frac15(2x+1)^5+C$$

Comment: Multiply and divide by two does not affect the result. Note that after that you got $2dx$.

Comment: ok then what is the initial point of adding it?

Comment: Let $u=2x-1$ then $du=2dx$ so $dx$ equals what?

Comment: To more cleary show the substitution rule for integrals. $(2x+1)' = 2$. But actually it has no use, the half is to cancel the $2$. And the $2$ is used for the substitution.

Comment: I still don't get it

Comment: so does it matter if in the final answer we have only 1/5 (2x +1) +c

Comment: The thinking is wouldn't it be nice if we had $2\,dx$ instead of $dx$? Then when we make the substitution $u=2x-1$, we would have $du$, that is, $2\,dx$, sitting in the integral. Too bad, there is no $2$ there. Put one in. That multiplies things by $2$. So multiply by $\frac{1}{2}$ in front to compensate. Easier, I think, is not to bother, let $u=2x-1$, then $dx=\frac{1}{2}du$.

Comment: Just a minor aside, regarding a typo (which started as a "hando" in the original, handwritten version of the equation):  there's a spurious sign change from $2x-1$ to $2x+1$.

Comment: True dat, @BarryCipra. I didn't even notice when I edited the question. I'll leave it as an exercise to the OP to correct the typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make the substitution $u=2x-1$, then $\,du = 2\,dx$.  Now, since $2\,dx$ doesn't appear in the integral, we make it appear by multiplying the integral by an appropriate form of 1, in particular $\dfrac{2}{2}$.  Thus,

$$\begin{aligned}\int (2x-1)^4\,dx &= \frac{2}{2}\int(2x-1)^4\,dx \\ &= \frac{1}{2}\int (2x-1)^4\cdot 2\,dx \\ &= \frac{1}{2}\int u^4\,du \\ &= \ldots\\ &= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{5}(2x-1)^5+C\end{aligned}$$

Does this clarify things?

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying by $2$ and $1/2$ is the same as multiplying by $1$: no change.

Pulling the $2$ into the integral lets you use the chain rule to simplify your expression:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int (2x-1)^4 (2\centerdot dx) = \frac{1}{2}\int u^4 du = \frac{1}{2} \frac{u^5}{5} + C = \frac{1}{10} (2x-1)^5 + C.$$

I let $u = 2x - 1$ so that $du = \frac{du}{dx}dx = 2 \centerdot dx$.

Comment: The entire purpose of multiplying by $2 \centerdot \frac{1}{2}$ was to use the chain rule. We did that on purpose. The $\frac{1}{2}$ appeared at the beginning when we did that. The $2$ was used for the chain rule. The $\frac{1}{2}$ didn't reappear; it never went away.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it doesn't look like you're familiar with the concept of substitution, so let's look at differentiation (I'll assume you know derivative properties and that an integral is the inverse of a derivative).

Let $I(s)=\int_0^s (2x+1)^4\text dx$.  Then $$\begin{align}\frac{\text dI(x)}{\text dx}&=(2x+1)^4\\
\frac{\text dI(\frac x2)}{\text d\frac x2}&=(x+1)^4\\
\frac{\text d\frac x2}{\text dx}\frac{\text dI(\frac x2)}{\text d\frac x2}&=\frac{\text d\frac x2}{\text dx}(x+1)^4\\
\frac{\text dI(\frac x2)}{\text dx}&=\frac 12(x+1)^4\tag{1}\\
\frac{\text dI(\frac x2-1)}{\text dx}&=\frac 12x^4\\
I\left(\frac x2-1\right)&=\frac1{10}x^5\end{align}$$
Note that $(1)$ is obtained by the chain rule.  $(1)$ is also equivalent to $\int (2x+1)^4\text dx=\frac12\int (2x+1)^4\text d(2x)$. By transforming $I$, we obtain $I(x)=\frac1{10}(2x+1)^5$.